# java.lang.NullPointer Exception Error click Back Button in webview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i have this problem : java.lang.NullPointerException

My Codes and LogCat pictures :

WebviewActivity.class

```
public class WebviewActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);



    Bundle alinan = getIntent().getExtras();
    String alinmis = alinan.getString("veri");



    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(alinmis);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);     
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
```

MenutrActivity.class

```
public class MenutrActivity extends Activity{

Bundle bnd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menutr);

    bnd = new Bundle();
    Button mekanlar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mekanlar);
    final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity.class);

    mekanlar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.WEBK"));
            String myString = "http://www.google.com.tr";
            bnd.putString("veri", myString);
            i.putExtras(bnd);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });  }}
```

application fails when I press the button.

LogCat error : java.lang.NullPointerException in WebviewActivity.class

Comment: Post code, not pictures

Comment: ok, sorry i will edit

Comment: post your main activities XML

Answer (score 2):

First of all change "StartActivity(new Intent...." to "Intent i = new Intent(...". You call the activity before putting extra.

Next time just copy your code and paste as a code. This way it is very hard to see...

Comment: I have changed but still not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791482/start-activity-intent-on-clicking-text-inside-webview This should help.