# How to open specific activity on clicking on link?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am working on an android app in that i have added sharing whatsapp sharing feature,I have done it successfully,Now i want to open a specific activity of my android application  when user click on link i have shared.I have searched few links but no luck,I hope somebuddy will help me in this.

**Added manifest**

```
  <activity
            android:name=".ProductDescriptionActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.abc.allaboutcity.MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="http://allaboutcity.in"
                    android:pathPrefix="/allaboutcity" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="allaboutcity"
                    android:host="allaboutcity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Add your activity in manifest and set required intent filter and required scheme in it!

Comment: check this-:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791482/start-activity-intent-on-clicking-text-inside-webview

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

Comment: What kind of link you wants to share if you wants to sharing link of your domain and you want to link to your app activity then checkout https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Comment: @Xenolion -Thank you for your reference friend,But my question is no more related to this,What i need is when someone click a link(IN WHATSAPP) that is already shared from my app to whatsapp,iT SHOULD REDIRECT TO MY APPLICATION WITH SPECIFIC ACTIVITY OPEN.aRE YOU GETTING?

Comment: @NikhileshPatve-No no..I dont want to share anything,Sharing is done already,I want to open a specific activity when shared link from whatsapp is clicked..!

Comment: Looks like you did not search at all. Its all in android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html).Thx

Comment: Is it a specific link that user will click in `whatsapp` or any link that was shared by your application?

Comment: Check the answer given by another user below is what I was saying, It is what I was saying!

Comment: Its specific link with dynamic integer at end

Comment: @Xenolion - Thanks a lot...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add intent filter in your manifest file to activity that you want to open

```
<activity
    android:name="Your Activity"
    android:label="Your Activity Title"
    android:theme="Your Style">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="your url"
            android:path="/your path"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: In which actvity i should write this?

Comment: activity that you want to open, when link is clicked

Comment: Ok let me try this one,Thank you bro

Comment: Hello,It not showing my app when dialog open for application chooser "complete action using".

Comment: are you sure you are giving the right host and path also if your scheme is https please change it and try it again.

Comment: yes ,I have put the exact path that i am sharing,I have my url "http://allaboutcity.in",

Comment: try "www.allaboutcity.in" in host. `android:host="www.allaboutcity.in"` if you have path you need to put in path e.g. `android:path="/example"`

Comment: as i see in your edited question you add http in your host remove it. you just need to add host. you already define your scheme in scheme part if it is http or https.

Answer (score 0):

use this code In Your WebView Activity

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String action = intent.getAction();
      Uri data = intent.getData();

      Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.loadUrl(""+ data);
```

next, use this code in AndroidManifest.xml, its for all link (Https / Http):

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="http://allaboutcity.in"
                android:pathPrefix="/allaboutcity" />
            <data android:host="www.host.com" android:pathPattern="/movie/0.*/" android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```